# MAMP : dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart Referenced from: /System/Library

Tags: mamp, cacti

I'm trying to run cacti on my Mac running OS X 10.9.3. I'm using MAMP 3.0.5.

In the cacti control panel, I've got the following error message :

> dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libJPEG.dylib in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO.

Answer (score 30):

You need to go on /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin and rename envvars to _envvars and apache will start !

Comment: This one worked for me, don't know if it worked by itself though, I did what was mentioned in @Wilianto's response first, but then got the same error as ruffin.

Answer (score 9):

You can try this one, it works for me.

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib 
rm libjpeg.dylib  ln -s
/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Resources/libJPEG.dylib libJPEG.dylib
```

Reference: You can see more in this [article](https://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2012/12/11/homebrew-share-thumbnails-and-previews-on-os-x/).

Comment: Then I get `Symbol not found: __cg_TIFFClientOpen`. Seems something is broken in the MAMP install.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is MAMP but not cacti cause the problem

Here is a simple way to solve the problem. Just comment out several lines in the `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars` file.
Here is the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10125539/3574916).

The original question is :
[ffmpeg MAMP “dyld: Library not loaded” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107671/ffmpeg-mamp-dyld-library-not-loaded-error)

This question has even detailed answers about reasons of the error. But I think the solution above works effectively.

[Conflict between dynamic linking priority in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643509/conflict-between-dynamic-linking-priority-in-osx)