# MampStack stopped working after upgrading to Yosemite and Xcode 6.3.2

Tags: xcode, mamp, osx-yosemite, dylib, bitnami

My installation of MampStack (Version 5.3.10) stopped working after upgrading to Yosemite and Xcode 6.3.2

In the log I have these type of errors:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Expected in: /Applications/MampStack/common/lib/libJPEG.dylib
in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

I tried to apply the principles of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598566/mamp-dyld-symbol-not-found-cg-jpeg-resync-to-restart-referenced-from-sys), but without success.

What could be a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with this workaround:

```
/Applications/MampStack/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh
```

I added at the beginning:

```
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And restarted MySQL