# Link issue of ImageMagick on Mac 10.11.1

Tags: macos, imagemagick-convert

I have just installed ImageMagick on Mac 10.11.1, but can't run the command, "convert". I received the following error message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set in the .bash_profile.

dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/ImageMagick-6.9.2/lib//libjpeg.9.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: `The DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set in the .bash_profile.`  this is pretty explicit...

Comment: I got the same error when it was set...

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598566/mamp-dyld-symbol-not-found-cg-jpeg-resync-to-restart-referenced-from-sys) helps ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since I don't have MAMP installed...

Comment: Look at the answer of the given link & try to adapt it to your case ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me at least, the answer is to simply remove the offending library (libraries in my case) from /usr/local/ImageMagick-6.9.2/lib/ as then the default ones are picked up -- no need for symlink(s).