# dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart

Tags: dyld

I'm trying to run a java version of [PowerLoom](http://www.isi.edu/isd/LOOM/PowerLoom/), but when I try to start it in the terminal, I get the following error message:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

This seems like a very similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598566/mamp-dyld-symbol-not-found-cg-jpeg-resync-to-restart-referenced-from-sys), except that the answers are specific to MAMP/Cacti. Any tips on how to deal with this, or even what this error message really means?

Answer (score 50):

If using `Qt Creator`, you have to uncheck the `Add build library search path to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` option from the `Run` section in the `Projects` tab:

[image: qtcreator]

Answer (score 12):

You could try this in shell:

```
$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources

$ sudo ln -sf libJPEG.dylib /usr/local/lib/libJPEG.dylib

$ sudo ln -sf libPng.dylib /usr/local/lib/libPng.dylib

$ sudo ln -sf libTIFF.dylib /usr/local/lib/libTIFF.dylib

$ sudo ln -sf libGIF.dylib /usr/local/lib/libGIF.dylib
```

Comment: this one worked me in Laravel for `php artisan` command

Comment: I was getting this error when trying to open MacVim. This did the trick!

Answer (score 11):

This issue may be down to the application in question dynamically linking to the wrong version of the [libJPEG.dylib] library (it's also possible the correct version has been overwritten/modified). As explained in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643509/conflict-between-dynamic-linking-priority-in-osx) it is a problem that can occur when an application alters environment variables that control dynamic linking library location (e.g.  On MacOS: `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` - more info see `man dyld`; On Linux: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - see `man ld.so`). It may be down to other factors such as dynamic link library config files but they have a system wide affect. You'll need to locate the variable setup in the application files and change it so that it prioritises the system paths e.g. (for MacOS):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/:ADDITION_LIBRARY_PATH_LOCATION
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the issue.

Comment: Why's that - could you not locate the setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH? The setting of that variable certainly can be a factor that causes the problem as I experienced it myself - and this fixed it. Or if you think it's down to another factor then add another answer to the question.

Comment: I have a situation here where DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set, yet I see the same issue. In my case I want to compile something with cargo (`cargo install svgbob_cli`) Linking into /usr/local/lib (as outlined below) works.

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit to include info on MacOS and Linux info regarding dynamic linking setup/config - there's quite a few other options mentioned in the man pages that might help with your issue.

Answer (score 8):

You likely have HomeBrew installed (or something like it). Something is setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/local/lib first and you get a collision with Jpeg installed in `/usr/local/lib/libJPEG.dylib` instead of using the system version.

The (wrongly demoted) answer given by @Pierz above is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by having set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to help a program find a missing library. The path I set also contained libjpeg, which was a different version from the system version that the program was expecting.

The solution was to set `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` instead, so that the library path was only used for things that couldn’t be found otherwise, not to override system libraries.